# Graph API Returning All Status Results as Undefined

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a search bar that queries Facebook for results. When I type a word to search and click search, I get results but anyone who posted a "Status"....I get a lot of undefined fields. So it says "'User' shared a status", and under it the photo section says undefined, and there's no actual status. It's blank. How can I fix this?

Anything else is fine...."'User shared a photo" shows the photos they shared. There is also a description...sometimes. Shared a link works too.

I also want to be able to type more than one word in the search bar, and be able to search again. As of now, you have to refresh the page in order to search again.

I've checked other topics for an answer, but the topics aren't how I'm doing the search. I haven't found an answer yet. Hopefully someone can help! Thanks....Here's a link to the page where my search bar is. I'll include my code as well.  http://ericnaff.com/html5/p3/ Also- How can I make it so "enter/return" starts the search as well?

Code-

```
function searchFB(userSearchparameter) {

    $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=' + userSearchparameter + '&callback=?', function(fbResults){
        $.each(fbResults.data, function() {
            // Data Templating
            $('<article class="fbResults"></article>').append ( 

                '<section class="resultsSource"><h6 class="shareHeader">' +
                '<img class="fromUser" src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + this.from.id + '/picture" height="50" width="50" alt="' + this.from.name + '">' +
                '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + this.from.id + '" class="fromName">' + this.from.name +'</a> shared a <a class="typeLink" href="' + this.link + '">' + this.  
                type + '</a> </h6>' +
                '<time class="createdTime" datetime="' + this.created_time + '">' + fuzzyFacebookTime(this.created_time.replace(/-/g,'/')) + ' &middot;</time>' +
                '<img class="typeLinkIcon" src="' + this.icon + '" alt="icon"></section>' +
                '<section class="resultsDescription"><h6><a class="shareLink" href="' + this.link + '">' +
                '<img class="sharePicture" src="' + this.picture + '" height="90" width="90" alt="' + this.name +'">' +
                '<span class="shareName">' + this.name + '</span>' +
                '<span class="shareCaption">' + this.caption + '</span>' +
                '<span class="shareDescription">' + this.description + '</span>' +
                '</a></h6></section>' +
                '<iframe class="linkShare" src="http://facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.link + '"></iframe>'
            ).appendTo('body');

            $('.fbResults section.resultsDescription span:contains(undefined)').remove();
        })
    })
}
$("button.startSearch").click(function() {
    var searchThis = $('.searchQuery').val();
    searchFB(searchThis);
});
```

Comment: Facebook's documentation is terrible. I've been through it a million times. It's almost like whoever wrote the documentation, didn't know what they were writing about.

Comment: I still get the problem on posts that are "shared a status".

Comment: I got status to show what someone wrote by changing this.description to this.message. Still no icon or image, maybe because they didn't include one. Still need to work on using enter/return to initiate the search, and a couple other items

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've gotten it figured out. http://ericnaff.com/html5/p3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out a solution for all of the undefined results. Here’s my code-

```
$('.fbResults').find('img[src="undefined"]').remove();
```

I also took care of using `ENTER`/`RETURN` to initiate the search with the `.keypress` function, like so-

```
$("input.searchQuery").keypress(function(event) {
$('.fbResults').remove();
if (event.which == 13) {                        //enter
event.preventDefault();
```

That code also refreshed results.

Thanks for any help received.